# Why Azure portal is showing Redis Connections Connected client 4.99K?

Tags: stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I have singleton azure-redis database client used in our application. However on Azure portal it shows connected clients 4.99K. I am not sure who are those clients and why it is showing 4.99K clients connected when I have singleton instance?

Sample Code:

```
using StackExchange.Redis;
if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            _cacheService = GetConnectionMultiplexer();
                            instance = _cacheService.GetDatabase();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Could it be possible that you have any other clients connected such as tools like redis-cli etc?

Comment: Take a look at this post to make sure you aren't hitting one of the issues identified there:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033488/why-are-connections-to-azure-redis-cache-so-high

Comment: @pranavrastogi No, I do not have any other clients connected.

Comment: @JonCole Yes!!! thank you very much. I think that could the issue. I am updating the library and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our discussion in comments, this is the same issue as described here:

[Why are connections to Azure Redis Cache so high?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033488/why-are-connections-to-azure-redis-cache-so-high)